# Python variable won't update outside of module

Tags: python, variables, module, scope

I have a variable called store_number that I pass in from my main.py into a module called store_selector which increments the store number until it finds a valid store. The whole thing is in a while loop and after the first loop the store variable does not keep it's updated value from the store_selector module but instead reverts to it's original value. I know this has something to do with declaring a global variable but the problem is if I declare a global variable inside the module I assume it will keep assigning the initial value when that module is called (since it's in a while loop in the main.py)

Any ideas?

Inside main.py

```
store_number = 103

while store_number < 10000:
    store_dropdown(driver)
    store_selector(driver, store_number)
    item_inspector(driver)
```

Inside functions.py

```
def store_selector(driver, store_number):
    textbox = driver.find_element(By.ID, "myStore-formInput")
    #time.sleep(1)
    store_number += 1
    textbox.send_keys(store_number, Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(1)
    while driver.find_element(By.ID, "myStore-errorMessage").is_displayed() and store_number < 10000:
        store_number += 1
        textbox.clear()
        textbox.send_keys(store_number, Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        store_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'button[data-storeid="{str(store_number).zfill(4)}"]')
        store_button.click()
```

Comment: When you call `store_selector` in `main.py`, you aren't sending `store_number` into the function - only its value, 103. The `store_number` inside `store_selector` is its own thing - it's a coincidence it has the same name and value as the one in `main.py`. So when `store_selector` updates its `store_number`, it isn't updating the one in `main.py` at all.

Comment: In fact I just gave the same explanation [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71027879/2449857)

Comment: @Jack the two are slightly different questions, one has to do with variable scope and the one you answered is to do with mutable vs immutable types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move `store_number+=1` into your main script

```
store_number = 103

while store_number < 10000:
    store_dropdown(driver)
    store_selector(driver, store_number)
    item_inspector(driver)
    store_number+=1
```

Or if you insist on doing so in `store_selector`, return the incremented value to the main function

```
store_number = 103

while store_number < 10000:
    store_dropdown(driver)
    store_number = store_selector(driver, store_number)
    item_inspector(driver)
```

and

```
def store_selector(driver, store_number):
    store_number += 1

    ########
    # Your function
    ########

    return store_number
```

You should really be using the first solution unless you have a really good reason to be incrementing your counter in the function (i.e. conditional incrementation)

Comment: Thank you. I had to go with the second solution since the first one ended in the same outcome.

Comment: You've probably implemented the first solution wrong, see [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Pzm/NK8ktUjBVsGAqzwjMydVASpiY2hgxcVZUJSZV6IBFdLk4oSytG0N//8HAA) for a simplified example. You really should be using the first example for your problem