# I think it's a basic question but I don't get why I get 0 in this function

Tags: python

```
a = 0

def add(number):
    number += 1
    return number

for i in range(20):
    add(a)

print(a)
```

I'm wondering why I get 0 for the print(a) call in the last line.
I put 0 for the first loop of the add()function and it should return 1 and so on in the for loop.
What am I missing?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the return value. `a = add(a)`.

Comment: Variables are passed by value. Assigning to `number` doesn't have any effect on `a`.

Comment: Integers (and a lot of types) are immutable in Python. You need to assign the return value of `add(a)` to a variable (which can just be a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just missing assigning the return value of `add()` back to `a`. Without the assignment, `a` never changes because function arguments are passed by value, not reference.

```
a = 0

def add(number):
    number += 1
    return number

for i in range(20):
    a = add(a)

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you aren't actually changing the value of `a`, try changing your `for` loop to look something like this:

```
for i in range(20):
    a = add(a)
```

To make use of the `return` keyword, make sure you understand that it sends back a value to the main program, treat it like another variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an `int` to a function, you're basically passing a copy of it. So your function adds 1 to a copy of `a` and returns it, but there's nothing there to catch the returned value.

When you pass a `list` or `dict` to a function, you're passing a reference to the original object, though. If you change it inside your function it changes thoughout your code:

```py
a = 0
b = [0]
c = {"engelbert": 0}

def add(number, lst, dct):
    number += 1
    lst[0] += 1
    dct["engelbert"] += 1
    # No return statement:
    # Function returns `None` by default

for i in range(20):
    add(a, b, c)

print(a, b, c)
# 0 [20] {'engelbert': 20}
```